# NullPointerException despite the fx:id and fx:controller are correct

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

I'am creating table with logs for my lan app. When I try run this app, it throws NullPointerException, but the fx:id and fx:controller are correct. I am using JavaFX 12.

I tried to refactor the fx:id and fx:controller with Intellij and Intellij  changes this correctly in logPane.fxml and in LogPaneController.class too, but it was still not working. If I comment line where exception is trowed, all of app working fine. I googled phrase "FXML component returns NUllPointerException", but result was always "your fx:id or fx:controller name is not the same in controller".

logPane.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.lanssmaker.controller.LogPaneController">
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="logTable" prefHeight="574.0" prefWidth="382.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                   AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn maxWidth="140.0" minWidth="70" prefWidth="70.0" text="Time"/>
                <TableColumn text="Content"/>
                <TableColumn maxWidth="140.0" minWidth="70" prefWidth="70.0" text="Category"/>
            </columns>
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
            </columnResizePolicy>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

LogPaneController.class

```js
public class LogPaneController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Log> logTable; //it's null

    public TableView<Log> getLogTableView() {
        return logTable;
    }


    public void initialize() {
        //example ussage calling NullPointerException
        logTable.isHover();
    }
}
```

Exception Log

```html
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Programming/Java/javastart/ssmaker/target/classes/fxml/buttonsPane.fxml
/D:/Programming/Java/javastart/ssmaker/target/classes/fxml/mainPane.fxml:17

 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1154)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
 at ssmaker/com.lanssmaker.main.Main.start(Main.java:16)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
 at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
 at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ssmaker/com.lanssmaker.controller.LogPaneController.initialize(LogPaneController.java:25)
 ... 33 more
```

```
package com.lanssmaker.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/mainPane.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("LAN ScreenShots Maker");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

mainPane.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="624.0" prefWidth="813.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lanssmaker.controller.MainController">
    <children>
        <HBox layoutX="158.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="624.0" prefWidth="813.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="25.0"
              AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">
            <children>
                <AnchorPane HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                    <children>
                        <VBox prefHeight="574.0" prefWidth="389.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                              AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <children>
                                <fx:include source="connectionPane.fxml"/>
                                <fx:include source="buttonsPane.fxml"/>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <fx:include source="logPane.fxml"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmGP.png)

Comment: When is your `LogPaneController.initialize()` method called? Inside of the constructor I guess?

Comment: @0x1C1B in Main class, FXMLLoader.load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a close look at the stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Programming/Java/javastart/ssmaker/target/classes/fxml/buttonsPane.fxml
/D:/Programming/Java/javastart/ssmaker/target/classes/fxml/mainPane.fxml:17
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ssmaker/com.lanssmaker.controller.LogPaneController.initialize(LogPaneController.java:25)
```

This means that the exception happends when you load `buttonsPane.fxml` when `FXMLLoader` deals with the

```xml
<fx:include source="buttonsPane.fxml"/>
```

element.

Furthermore it tells me that you're not only using `LogPaneController` for `logPane.fxml`, but also for `buttonsPane.fxml`. Seperate controller instances are created every time you load an fxml; using `<fx:include>` results in a seperate `FXMLLoader` instance being created to load the included fxml. The `logTable` field is only injected for one of them; for the other controller instance it remains `null`. (This is even ignoring the fact that loading `buttonsPane.fxml` happens before loading `logPane.fxml` so even if the same controller instance was used at the time loading `buttonsPane.fxml` completes, the `TableView` has not been created based on `logPane.fxml`.)

Use seperate controller classes for `buttonsPane.fxml` and `logPane.fxml`. You won't get both fxmls "to communicate" by simply using the same controller class. I'd suggest an alternative, but what you're doing there doesn't make any sense (except you trying to provoke a NPE): `isHover` simply retuns the value of the `hover` property which is always `false` for nodes that are not yet part of a `Scene`.

Comment: You have right, i miss and set wrong controller for buttonsPane. Now, it's working fine again. Thank you for explains and tip for future. I use isHover method only for test. Thank you very much bro! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have getter class for private logTable, so you can get a value, but I do not see the value initialization or setter class (which will initialize the value).

Comment: I add Main class and mainPane.fxml. In Main, FXMLLoader.load shoud load mainPane.fxml, where logPane.fxml is.